# Spring Security with # in URL Pattern

Tags: java, regex, spring, backbone.js, spring-security

I'm trying to get an app url pattern to match in security-http.xml and am running into some problems with the # symbol.

Here's a sample url:
http://localhost:8080/test/#test2/foo

Here's the security-http that I am trying to use to match it

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="^test/#test2/.*$" access="permitAll"/>
```

However, the "#" in the pattern does not seem to be working.

Any thoughts on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything after (and including) the hash (`#`) in a URL does not get sent in the request to the server so your server will never see that information.

Comment: Thank you, this makes total sense now!